# How does PowerPoint calculate the axis max?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Background: I'm trying to style a combo chart based on where the last value of one series falls relative the last value of the other series. In order to do this, I need to calculate their size in relation to their respective axes.

How does PowerPoint calculate the maximum value of an axis?

I've tried looking at various values from 4 to 10,000 to find a system, but I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office charts will maintain the same automatic maximum axis value until it is less than 5% larger than the chart element. Then it will increment the number chart gridlines by 1. So a column chart will have a maximum axis height of 6 as long as the tallest column is 5.71428571 or less.

Comment: I guess the related question then is how are the default gridline tick marks determined?

Comment: For the most part, Office takes the largest value and rounds it up to the next whole number, or number divisible by a regular number (like 5, 10, 20, etc.) for larger numbers.